# When is Application object reset?

Tags: asp-classic

If I put a string in the Application object, when will it be removed?

I want to cache a connection string within it, but if I update it, I'll need the instance in the object replaced.

Comment: The `Application` object lasts the duration of the web application and is only reset when the web application is stopped *(either manually or due to service or server restart)*.

Comment: It is ideal for storing connection strings *(not `ADODB.Connection` objects)*. To avoid having to restart the web application for new connection string to take affected consider setting the `Application` level connection string on `Session` start or building a simple script to update the connection string on the fly. Remember to use `Application.Unlock()` and `Application.Lock()` when updating `Application` variable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application level variables are ideal for storing Web Application configuration information.

### How long do they last?

`Application` variables last for the duration of the Web Application, this means that only stopping the Web Application will reset them.

Everything in the list will cause the `Application` object to reset.

- Manually stopping the Web Application in IIS.
- Stopping the World Wide Web Publishing Service.
- Restarting the Web Server.

### What about updates?

The one drawback with the longevity is updates would require the Web Application to be restarted. Luckily though there are ways around this.

#### Sessions

Using the `global.asa` file in the root of the Web Application we can take advantage of the `Session_OnStart()` event to trigger an update of the `Application` variable.

```vb
Sub Session_OnStart
  'Make sure multiple sessions aren't trying to update the value of
  'Application("ConnString") at the same time.
  Application.Lock
  Application("ConnString") = "..."
  Application.Unlock
End Sub
```

#### Update using a script

If `Session`'s are undesirable you can just call the update manually.

```vb
Application.Lock
Application("ConnString") = "..."
Application.Unlock
```

Comment: Shouldn't "Unlock" and "Lock" be the other way around?